# Was Shanks expected to eat the Gomu Gomu no Mi?

Tags: one-piece

At the beginning of the series, we see Shanks carrying the Gomu Gomu no Mi fruit around like a treasure. Was he expected to eat this fruit? Or did he just sell it?

[image]

It's obvious he didn't want Luffy to eat it.

Comment: I don't think there is a clear answer, for this question.We know how he took it http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Gomu_Gomu_no_Mi .But I would bet he wanted to sell it, because if he wanted to eat he could have done it or maybe to give it to someone he would also would have done, except if it was someone not from his crew.. (or maybe impress a girl :P)

Comment: Didn´t his crew also mention the estimated price they expected to get? So they planned to sell it. (But I may remember it wrong)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think Shanks ever planned to eat the Gomu Gomu no Mi. I think he probably gave it to one of his crew members or sold it for some sake. With Shanks being one of the most powerful men in the world, I think if he ever wanted a Devil Fruit, he would have been able to get one pretty easily. If he wanted the Gomu Gomu no Mi specifically, then it would be a different story. However, I just can't think of any reason why he could have wanted that one Devil Fruit. There are more powerful fruits to go after which would suit him better, I think.

Comment: Pirate Kings devil fruit is still not certain. Maybe he ate gomu gomu no mi and when Pirate King died the fruit respawned and shanks searched it in east blue and when he finally found it luffy ate it? Just a theory why Shanks could have wanted it.

Answer (score 1):

When Luffy ate the fruit, Shanks was even quoted as saying that Not Being Able to Swim is a pirate's biggest weakness
[image]
[image]

Based on Shank's reaction it's reasonable to assume that he wouldn't have eaten or let his crew eat the devil fruit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe he was looking for that specific Devil Fruit, nor do I believe he intended to eat it himself. I believe he simply came across this Devil Fruit by pure chance or by taking it from another pirate crew who he happened to fight, and intended to sell it; if another member of his crew wanted to eat it, they probably would've done so before Shanks even arrived at Fuschia Village.

Answer (score 0):

I think he wanted to eat it because he knew what the fruit is capable of otherwise he could not kept the devil fruit with him. That's what i think

Comment: Would you like to expand on your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I sincerely think Shanks had the gum gum no mi for his personal consumption. As we know, Shanks knew everything about the fruit and its ability of gum. Now we all know that gum can be modified into anything as we see the straw hat's gears.

So imagine someone like Shanks with tremendous Haki ability having to be able to use the gum gum power. For all you know, he could have already been the king of the pirates by now with that ability. And if you think it over, Shanks left the previous Kings straw hat with Luffy probably because he knew that with that determination, ability, and haki (as he was friends with Garp), Luffy would actually have the potential to be the pirate king.

Comment: Welcome to [anime.se]. This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. Compared to a forum, an answer is not a "reply", and "share your thought" doesn't belong on the answer. Consider taking a quick [tour] to understand how this site works.

Answer (score -1):

He didn't wanted to eat it, that's for sure because if he wanted to do so he would've done it for himself or for one of his nakama.
Secondly he is a Pirate and the fact that he was safe-guarding the fruit was to secure the fruit until he sells it.
It would've been probably for selling but you can't say this for sure on any grounds and only Oda would've answered it the best!